# How to trigger a ValueListener with the same value

Tags: juce

I listen to a Value that contains the path of a file to load.   I would like to load the same file, but the listener system won't react unless the path is different from the last event.

How can one get ValueListener to trigger on the same data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a class derived from `Value::ValueSource` that has its own overridden implementation of `setValue()` that's something like this:

```
void setValue (const var& newValue) override
{
   // base class version checks for equality first. Skip that
   // and always set the value and notify of changes.
   value = newValue;
   sendChangeMessage (false);
}
```

Second, when creating the `Value` object, pass in a pointer to a new instance of this class, like

```
Value myValue(new EagerValueSource());
```

and then use the `Value` object exactly as you otherwise would have, except listeners will be notified whenever `myValue`'s `setValue()` method is called, regardless of whether that's actually a new value or not.